# crosscompiling asm error

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am compiling this function using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, but it is giving me an error
       `expected string literal before ‘)’ token`

```
void flush_icache(void)
{
  u32 tmp = 0;
  asm volatile(" mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c5, 0\n\t": : "r"(tmp) : );
}
```

which I am not able to remove.
If anyone has any idea then kindly resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, there was a problem in using crosstool-chain. So previously I was using an older one provided by codesourcery(2008), then I moved to 2010 toolchain.
That might be an issue with changing architecture of ARM.

Comment: IIRC older crosstool-chain has a bug, I updated toolchain to 2010 one, which resolved the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe put a space between the "r" and "(tmp")?

Here's the documentation on GCC "extended ASM commands":

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars

This link might also help:

- http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html

============= ADDENDUM =============

One other suggestion:

```
void flush_icache(void)
{
  u32 tmp = 0;
  asm volatile(
    " mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c5, 0\n\t" 
    :             /* no output registers */
    : "r"(tmp)    /* input */
  );
}
```

Comment: separating by space does not work. By any chance can this be particular to some crosstool chain version ?